# LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

i am learning c++ for game dev i am reading a book and usin win32 api so i tried to compile a test of my program

```
 #include <windows.h>

        int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInsance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,PSTR cmdLine,int showCmd){
            MessageBox(0,"First Win32 Program","Window Tittle",MB_OK);
            }
```

i am getting:

LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMainCRTStartup

i am new in win32 programming so i dont know where is the error i am using windows7 thnx :)!

Comment: I am quite inclined to downvote the question on the grounds that it provides no help to any other person with the same problem. If you have found a solution, post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: by default you don't get this error. it's a bit difficult to provoke. so the short answer is: don't do whatever it is you're doing.

Comment: which compiler / IDE are you using? Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and was solved when I realized that I had forgotten to add the source

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `/ENTRY:WinMain` to override the default name, or compile with `/MT` so the compiler will mark the object files in such a way that the linker grabs the runtime library (which provides an entry point).

The runtime library entry point does some nice things like run global constructors set up a global exception handler so you get a dialog box in case of uncaught exceptions, but nothing it does is absolutely necessary.

---

NOTE: If you don't use the library entry point, no arguments are available.  You have to use the OS functions such as `GetCurrentProcess` and `GetCommandLine` and `GetStartupInfo` instead to get the information normally available as `WinMain` arguments.  You weren't using any of that anyway.  But think twice about using your own entry point, a lot of stuff depends on the library initialization and you'd better be very sure you aren't using it.

Comment: @Rolando - please post (and mark as answer) your own answer then. Stack overflow is not just a place to ask questions, but to find answers.

Comment: -1 it's linker option `/ENTRY`, and `WinMain` does not have valid signature of an entry point. Besides you need the machinery (like initialization of statics) provided by a real entry point function. `WinMainCRTStartup` is one such.

Comment: @Alf: Corrected the name of the option, thanks.  And local statics are not initialized by the entry point, only globals and static class members are.  Finally, I stand by the last sentence in my answer.  You can write a program that doesn't need any initialization other than zero-fill, which the OS does.  But usually you want the library entry point, and I think my answer expresses that.  (I did check that his `WinMain` doesn't use any arguments, so it is a viable entry point.)

Comment: @Ben: the entry point signature is, AFAIK, undocumented. `WinMain` as entry point may work (with garbage values for arguments), or not. But **don't do it**, and don't give advice to others to do it. It's just undefined behavior.

Answer (score -2):

You really want to look into XNA for game dev. And for your first app - let the VC++ IDE do the heavy lifting. Choose New Project, Console App, then printf "Hello World" - all the defaults will be set for you -

Comment: XNA is not C++ and I doubt a C++ game dev book uses it. For the question presented, Ben's answer describes a solution.